# How to impersonate a *just* created user?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm using https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/insert to create a new user on my domain.

Immediately after, I want to change its calendar settings. When I attempt to impersonate the user I get the following error:

```
Signet::AuthorizationError: Authorization failed.  Server message:
{
 "error": "unauthorized_client",
 "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."
}
```

If I wait 20 seconds, I do not get this error. How do I immediately impersonate a newly created user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically answered your own question. You do sometimes have to wait a little bit in order to use a newly created entity. I saw this dealt with in [an example](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-attachments/google-api-dotnet-client/issue-401/comment-3/Program.cs) on a [google-api-dotnet-client issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/401) where you tell the program itself to wait a bit:

```
    Console.WriteLine("OrgUnit inserted: {0}\r\n", insertedOrgUnit.OrgUnitPath);
    // That should've worked okay.

    Console.WriteLine("Pausing for ten seconds because sometimes you can't retrieve something immediately after you've created it...\r\n");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Comment: Yeah, I implemented a retry system to solve this. The downvotes to the question sapped my motivation to write an answer. I'll tick yours.